# Form returned bad request: Missing required parameters: id

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-form

I'm new to yii2 and I want to make a signup form using yii2 basic
I use the generated mvc from gii but when i submit the registration it returned bad request but some of the data i've input is in the database but some are missing too.
Here is my user model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "user".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $name
 * @property string $password
 * @property string $authKey
 * @property int $id_level
 * @property string $accessToken
 *
 * @property MasterLevel $level
 */
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['username', 'name', 'password', 'authKey', 'id_level', 'accessToken'], 'required'],
            [['id_level'], 'integer'],
            [['username'], 'string', 'max' => 30],
            [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            [['password', 'authKey'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
            [['accessToken'], 'string', 'max' => 10],
            [['id_level'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => MasterLevel::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['id_level' => 'id_level']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'username' => 'Username',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'password' => 'Password',
            'authKey' => 'Auth Key',
            'id_level' => 'Id Level',
            'accessToken' => 'Access Token',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Gets query for [[Level]].
     *
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getLevel()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(MasterLevel::className(), ['id_level' => 'id_level']);
    }
     public $id;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $authKey;
    public $accessToken;


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return isset(self::$users[$id]) ? new static(self::$users[$id]) : null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        foreach (self::$users as $user) {
            if ($user['accessToken'] === $token) {
                return new static($user);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
        foreach (self::$users as $user) {
            if (strcasecmp($user['username'], $username) === 0) {
                return new static($user);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->authKey;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->authKey === $authKey;
    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param string $password password to validate
     * @return bool if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return $this->password === $password;
    }
}
```

And my actionCreate in user controller

```
 public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new User();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save(false)) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

the view

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\User */

$this->title = 'Create User';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Users', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="user-create">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <?= $this->render('_form', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]) ?>

</div>
```

I can't find where my code is wrong
Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`save(false)` method does not **validate** your data!
That's why some data may not be included in the database.

Consider the following:

1- The data of your `rules()` method must match the database.(**rules()** In model file)

2- Use the following in action:

```
 if ($model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()){
    #Code ...
```

**Or**:

```
 if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()){

    #Code ...
      if ($model->save(false)){
    #Code ...
```